# Duplicated rows with subquery in select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm learning database with SQL Server and the duplication confuses me:

```sql
SELECT t.tno, t.tname, classes = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM teaching te WHERE te.tno = t.tno)
FROM teacher t, teaching t2
WHERE t.tno = t2.tno AND t2.Llanguage = 'English'
```

if I use the code above, I will get a result with many duplicated rows like this:

```
+------+----------+-------+
|tno   |tname     |classes|
+------+----------+-------+
|T01   |t1        |3      |
|T01   |t1        |3      |
|T03   |t3        |4      |
|T03   |t3        |4      |
|T03   |t3        |4      |
|T04   |t4        |3      |
|T05   |t5        |3      |
|T05   |t5        |3      |
+------+----------+-------+
```

However, if I don't use the subquery, the duplication would not happen. Could some one help me?

**Update 10/14**: the data inside `teacher` and `teaching`:

```
teacher:
+------+----------+---+----------+--------------------+
|tno   |tname     |sex|birthday  |title               |
+------+----------+---+----------+--------------------+
|T01   |t1        |m  |1980-06-10|lecturer            |
|T02   |t2        |f  |1970-03-14|professor           |
|T03   |t3        |m  |1973-04-20|associate professor |
|T04   |t4        |m  |1981-08-30|lecturer            |
|T05   |t5        |f  |1975-07-20| associate professor|
|T06   |t6        |m  |1980-09-19|lecturer            |
+------+----------+---+----------+--------------------+
teaching:
+------+------+----------+----+
|tno   |cno   |Llanguage |Year|
+------+------+----------+----+
|T01   |801   |English   |2018|
|T01   |803   |Bilingual |2018|
|T01   |804   |English   |2018|
|T02   |801   |Bilingual |2018|
|T02   |804   |Bilingual |2018|
|T03   |802   |English   |2018|
|T03   |804   |Bilingual |2018|
|T03   |805   |English   |2018|
|T03   |806   |English   |2018|
|T04   |802   |Bilingual |2018|
|T04   |803   |English   |2018|
|T04   |805   |Bilingual |2018|
|T05   |801   |Bilingual |2018|
|T05   |802   |English   |2018|
|T05   |803   |English   |2018|
|T06   |803   |Bilingual |2018|
|T06   |806   |Bilingual |2018|
+------+------+----------+----+
```

For the join style, the slide my teacher using is very out-dated (maybe 10 years ago?). In fact the code was written a few weeks ago and now I have been used to using the `inner join`. However, I still confuse about this problem.

Comment: If you are learning SQL, learn proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: That subquery will *not* produce extra rows, so the subquery is not causing that. Also, if you *are* learning SQL, then why are you starting with that outdated ANSI-89 JOIN syntax? It was superseded by the ANSI-92 JOIN syntax 28 years ago. [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: The only thing that will produce more rows is your implicit `JOIN` to the table `teaching ` in your `FROM`. The `SELECT` does not affect the row count of a query.

Comment: It looks like several of the teachers have multiple rows with multiple languages.

Comment: We really need some sample data and expected results to know what is happening.

Comment: It seems you don't know what a join does exactly. It combines every row in the first table with every row in the second table where the two rows meet your criteria. Thus row data gets duplicated. I have updated my answer to illustrate this.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting duplicates, because a teacher can teach multiple English classes. You show each teacher as often as they have an English class.

What the query is supposed to do (or what I *assume* it is supposed to do): Show all teachers that teach at least one English class with their overall class count. The condition "that teach at least one English class" is a condition that you can check after aggregating the teachers' rows, so place it in the `HAVING` clause.

```
select t.tno, t.tname, count(t2.tno) as classes
from teacher t
inner join teaching t2 on t.tno = t2.tno
group by t.tno, t.tname
having count(case when t2.language = 'English' then 1 end) > 0
```

I don't know whether SQL Server actually requires `t.tname` in the `GROUP BY` clause. Standard SQL doesn't, because `t.tno` should uniquely define one teacher which includes their name.

And as has been mentioned by others: If you are taught to use comma-separated joins, then better quit your class, tutorial or book.

**UPDATE:** You have edited your request and still seem to be confused with the result of the join. To illustrate what is happening in the join:

teacher:

```
+------+----------+---+----------+--------------------+
|tno   |tname     |sex|birthday  |title               |
+------+----------+---+----------+--------------------+
|T01   |t1        |m  |1980-06-10|lecturer            |
|T02   |t2        |f  |1970-03-14|professor           |
+------+----------+---+----------+--------------------+
```

teaching:

```
+------+------+----------+----+
|tno   |cno   |Llanguage |Year|
+------+------+----------+----+
|T01   |801   |English   |2018|
|T01   |803   |Bilingual |2018|
|T01   |804   |English   |2018|
|T02   |801   |Bilingual |2018|
|T02   |804   |Bilingual |2018|
+------+------+----------+----+
```

Teachers joined with English classes:

```
+------+----------+------+-----------+--------------------+-------+-------+-------------+--------+
|t.tno |t.tname   |t.sex |t.birthday |t.title             |t2.tno |t2.cno |t2.Llanguage |t2.Year |
+------+----------+------+-----------+--------------------+-------+-------+-------------+--------+
|T01   |t1        |m     |1980-06-10 |lecturer            |T01    |801    |English      |2018    |
|T01   |t1        |m     |1980-06-10 |lecturer            |T01    |804    |English      |2018    |
+------+----------+------+-----------+--------------------+-------+-------+-------------+--------+
```

of which you are showing the first two columns plus the teaching count for the tno:

```
+------+----------+--------+
|t.tno |t.tname   |classes |
+------+----------+--------+
|T01   |t1        |3       |
|T01   |t1        |3       |
+------+----------+--------+
```

Comment: :P I wanna quit too, however it's a compulsory course

Answer (score -1):

1. Use explicit joins. `Left outer` or `Inner only` as you are learning.
   try not to use `inner joins` unless your tables force constraints.
2. Never put a subscript in the select statement. On large tables you'll overwhelm the system.
3. the group by allows control over definition of unique rows and aggregations.

```sql
SELECT t.tno, t.tname, classes =  COUNT(*)      
FROM teacher t
LEFT OUTER JOIN teaching t2 ON  t.tno = t2.tno    
WHERE t2.Llanguage = 'English'  AND t2.tno IS NOT NULL    
GROUP BY t.tno, t.tname
```

Comment: "Never put a subscript in the select statement" what does that mean? What is a sub-script? Do you mean a sub-query? If so, your advice is wrong. Sub-queries are fine, they are no different to a join. Also there is no reason not to use inner joins if that describes the relationship.

Comment: You can put the subquery anywhere in the script. However, there are ramifications when you are dealing with large tables.  So if there are 500k rows, and you put the sub-query in the SELECT clause. The sub-query will run 500k times. If you put it in the FROM clause it runs once. I've taken scripts that vendors build like that and they take an hour to run and tweaked them to 20 seconds. If you're dealing with a  small database, you're right, all's good. Over time however, you'll slowly slow down your system.

Comment: That maybe true in some circumstances, but not as a generalisation. A join potentially has to lookup the same name of rows as a sub-query, and SQL Server is good at optimising that stuff so long as the correct indexes are in place. There are very few hard and fast rules when it comes to query design.

Comment: You are correct, there are times where it would create a unnecessary load.